# Selecting from a table having duplicate rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with columns a,b,c,d where I may have duplicate rows. How to select all unique rows from there by SQL.

Suppose my table is

```
a | b | c | d
--------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2 | 2
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
3 | 3 | 3 | 3
4 | 4 | 4 | 4
```

I want to extract only columns with unique rows:-

```
a | b | c | d
--------------
1 | 1 | 1 | 1
2 | 2 | 2 | 2
3 | 3 | 3 | 3
4 | 4 | 4 | 4
```

Is there any SQL to do this?

EDIT:

My bad I forgot to mention that I was running these queries on RedShift and that's why distinct was not working. Found the solution now.

Comment: have you tried using the distinct keyword?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT`.

```
select distinct a, b, c, d 
from your_table_name;
```

Also you can use `GROUP BY`.

```
select a, b, c, d 
from your_table_name
group by a, b, c, d;
```

I think `DISTINCT` would better in case of performance.